# The constructor for superclass is undefined

Tags: java

I have my main;

```
package lab8_9;
import se.lth.cs.ptdc.images.ImageFilter;
import se.lth.cs.ptdc.images.ImageGUI;

public class ImageProcessor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImageFilter[] filters = new ImageFilter[2];
        filters[0] = new IdentityFilter("Identity Filter");
        filters[1] = new BlueFilter("Blue Filter");
        new ImageGUI(filters);
    }
}
```

then I have my class;

```
package lab8_9;
import java.awt.Color;
import se.lth.cs.ptdc.images.ImageFilter;

public class IdentityFilter extends ImageFilter {
    public IdentityFilter(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public Color[][] apply(Color[][] inPixels, double paramValue) {
        int height = inPixels.length;
        int width = inPixels[0].length;
        Color[][] outPixels = new Color[height][width];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                Color pixel = inPixels[i][j];           
                outPixels[i][j] = new Color(pixel.getRed(), 
                                            pixel.getGreen(),
                                            pixel.getBlue());
            }
        }
        return outPixels;
    }
}
```

Both of which works fine, but then I try to write my own class;

```
package lab8_9;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.ImageFilter;


public class BlueFilter extends ImageFilter {
    public BlueFilter(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public Color[][] apply(Color[][] inPixels, double paramValue) {
        int height = inPixels.length;
        int width = inPixels[0].length;
        Color[][] outPixels = new Color[height][width];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                Color pixel = inPixels[i][j];           
                outPixels[i][j] = new Color(0, 
                                            0,
                                            pixel.getBlue());
            }
        }
        return outPixels;
    }
}
```

I get two errors, one for my main;

```
filters[1] = new BlueFilter("Blue Filter");
```

"Type mismatch: cannot convert from BlueFilter to ImageFilter"

and one for the class I'm trying to add, in the constructor;

```
public BlueFilter(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
```

"The constructor ImageFilter(String) is undefined"

I am lost here, what is the problem? I pretty much copied IdentityFilter, which worked fine, yet it does not work. Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm a beginner, so please keep explain whatever I'm doing wrong.

Here is the superclass if anyone needs it, I have not written it;

```
package se.lth.cs.ptdc.images;
    import java.awt.Color;

    public abstract class ImageFilter {
        private String name;

        protected ImageFilter(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }


        public abstract Color[][] apply(Color[][] inPixels, double paramValue);

        protected short[][] computeIntensity(Color[][] pixels) {
            int height = pixels.length;
            int width = pixels[0].length;
            short[][] intensity = new short[height][width];
            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
                    Color c = pixels[i][j];
                    intensity[i][j] = (short) ((c.getRed() + c.getGreen() + c
                            .getBlue()) / 3);
                }
            }
            return intensity;
        }


        protected short convolve(short[][] p, int i, int j, short[][] kernel,
                int weight) {
            short sum = 0;
            for (int ii = -1; ii <= 1; ii++) {
                for (int jj = -1; jj <= 1; jj++) {
                    sum += p[i + ii][j + jj] * kernel[ii + 1][jj + 1];
                }
            }
            return (short) Math.round((double) sum / weight);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are importing `java.awt.image.ImageFilter;` instead of `se.lth.cs.ptdc.images.ImageFilter;`.

Comment: Oh wow, that was a very fast answer :), thanks. Now my program works fine!